# mak a uiimageView turn around another image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, uiimageview

here is my question.
I would like to animate an image, I would like to make it turn around another image, but I don't know how to do that. I just want that it turns( not a rotation but a movement of turning like it is turning around a circle).how can I do this please ?

---

here is my code :

```
-(void){
CALayer *orbit1 = [CALayer layer];
orbit1.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
orbit1.position = centre.center;
orbit1.cornerRadius = 100;
orbit1.borderColor= [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
orbit1.borderWidth = 1.5;

planet1 = [CALayer layer];
planet1.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44.0, 20.0);
planet1.position = CGPointMake(160, 25);
planet1.contents = (id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"bouletest_05.png"].CGImage);
[orbit1 addSublayer:planet1];

CABasicAnimation *anim1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
anim1.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
anim1.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
anim1.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
anim1.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim1.duration = 10.0;
[orbit1 addAnimation:anim1 forKey:@"transform"];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:orbit1];
```

}

and then :

```
-(void)creation{

imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"]];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView2];
imageView2.center=planet1.center;
}
```

look at the  last line: imageView2.center=planet1.center; the problem is here

Comment: Check [Quartz 2D Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-SW1) . It explains it very well.

Answer (score 3):

Check this post: http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-4. There you'll find an example of how to animate view along arbitrary UIBezierPath.

So in your case you'll need to create a circle path around your 'anchor' image:

```
const CGFloat radius = 100.0f;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(center.x-radius, center.y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius)];
```

and add CAKeyFrameAnimation with that path to the image view you want to move.

Comment: sorry but I have a little problem when I want to add CAKeyFrameAnimation with that path to the image view I don't know how to do please can you help me

Comment: @Valentin, follow the blog post linked - it shows how to add animation. Do you have any specific problems with what is described there?

Comment: yes I never use bezierPAth etc... when I write on xcode -(void) {then your code} it doesn't work nothing happen on the screen

Comment: oh sorry I understand now . but now I have another problem I would like to use the image that is turning, more precisly its center to assign it to other images but wen I use the center xcode tell me request for member 'center' something not a structure  or union

Comment: @valentingougeau how exactly you want to do that? (post code may be)

Comment: CALayer does not have center property - you should use position instead (you'll need to make some simple calculations to get layer's center from its position and bounds properties)

Comment: yes but the position doesn't move I want that imageView2.center is equal to the position of planet1 which is moving

Comment: @valentingougeau, then you need to add it as subview/sublayer to moving layer, or add the same animation to it.

Comment: Its better to focus on one problem in one question. If further discussion goes far from initial question it may be worth to open new question about new problem (also to avoid long discussions in comments which is now discouraged on SO)